# Detect bottom of the page on scroll using Vanilla JS in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I am developing a React Application and want to Detect the bottom of the page on user scroll using Vanilla JS. I googled it out and found that below check works fine for most of the scenarios -

```
window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight
```

It works fine yes when in my react application I have not set height as 100vh in my App.css and index.css. But after setting the height as 100vh in both of them it does not.

I was consoling the values of above params **without height as 100vh** and below was the output on Galaxy S5 device -

```
window.innerHeight->  640 window.scrollY -> 0 document.body.offsetHeight->  265
```

[image]

Consoling the values of above params **with height as 100vh** and below was the output on Galaxy S5 device -

```
window.innerHeight->  640 window.scrollY -> 0 document.body.offsetHeight->  640
```

[image]

Below is handleScroll code:

```
  handleScroll = () => {
    const {
      totalUsersCount, users, currentPage, fetchUsersList,
    } = this.props;
    console.log('window.innerHeight-> ', window.innerHeight, 'window.scrollY ->', window.scrollY,
      'document.body.offsetHeight-> ', document.body.offsetHeight);
    if (((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight)) {
      fetchUsersList(currentPage + 1);
    }
  };
```

How can I check for the bottom of page scroll, when the height is set as 100vh in Vanilla JS as I doing it in React.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `document.body.scrollHeight` to get the actual height.

Reference : https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll-window#width-height-of-the-document

UPDATED: 
for a specific element use any of the selectors and get its scroll height.

```
const el = document.getElementById('#id');
const scrollHeight = el.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: I need to use document.body.scrollHeight in place of which variable ?

Comment: `scrollHeight` properly is present for any Element. you could use it use it on the `body` of the `document`, hence `document.body.scrollHeight` or for a specific element see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

When you set body height to 100vh, scrollHeight will remain the height of your window, whatever total content length actually is. scrollHeight doesn't actually return the height of your whole content (as you'd expect), but the visible space in which it can scroll.

What you want is not `height` css property value but `max-height`.

Try changing your css to

```css
body {
  /* height: 100vh; */
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Also I don't think it is good to rely on window height for this, since you might later want to wrap your scrollable area (by adding a header for example), thus you'll loss some extra weight and might get errors in your calculation. If you have a reference (wether in React or with vanilla DOM parsing) to the element that handle the scroll (the one that contains your scrollbar), you can use the following test in your scroll function :

```js
handleScroll = () => {
  //...
  if (target.scrollTop >= (target.scrollHeight - target.offsetHeight)) {
    //... your stuff
  }
}
```

Since for now body is your target, you can just :

```js
handleScroll = () => {
  //...
  if (document.body.scrollTop >= (document.body.scrollHeight - document.body.offsetHeight)) {
    //... your stuff
  }
}
```